# View raw diff of one file in different branches

Tags: github, diff

It is possible to view a diff between two branches. For example I can compare the branch t9 and t10 like this: https://github.com/astridx/boilerplate/compare/t9...t10

Further it is possible to get the *raw* value of this diff adding the extension `.diff`: https://github.com/astridx/boilerplate/compare/t9...t10.diff

Is it possible to get the diff of **one file** in this branches in raw form?

Comment: This isn't a question about Git, but rather about GitHub. I've edited the tags. Note, though, that there's no such thing as a "diff of one file": a diff is always of two files, or two trees. If GitHub have an interface that will produce a single-file diff it probably takes two specific commits and a path name, or two commits and two paths names, or two blob hash IDs.